# Sqlalchemy Integer or BigInteger to hold the value of a sequence?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

The DB is Postgresql.

On it, from what I saw, sequences use 64 bits.

I have created a sequence. I use it in my code by fetching its next value and saving it to a field in a table.

Of what Sqlalchemy type should such field be?
`Integer` or `BigInteger`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is `BigInteger`, as on Postresql a sequence has a size of 64 bits, as it says [here in the notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html)

> Sequences are based on bigint arithmetic, so the range cannot exceed the range of an eight-byte integer (-9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807).

Type sizes are listed [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html)